# Label,TextBox,Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

I have a label and a text box associated to it . I have added some text in text box which is invisible at first...  now I want to display the content after I go On the label...

Comment: @viahai: there's no such thing as "C#.NET".

Comment: "Double" post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537171/its-about-the-label-associated-with-the-text-box

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an HTML label rather than an ASP label, you can use the onmouseover event.  From within this event, you can then turn on/off the visibility of the text.

Comment: Yes I am Using the HTML label . Can You Give me The Code For The Same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show one textbox after typing something in another, you can use the javascript onBlur() event to show it.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery it can be:

$("#MyLabel").mouseover(function(){
         $("#MyTextBox").attr("visible","true");
});