# How can I display a text box's content when the cursor touches the associated label?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a label and a text box associated with it. I have added some text in the text box which is invisible at first; I want to display the content after the cursor moves on the label.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[onmouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onmouseover)** and **[onmouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.onmouseout)** event on the label. If you can use a framework like jQuery you can use the hover function.

See a **[working demo](http://jsbin.com/adedu3)**.

Answer (score 0):

This is to handle on mouse move in client side javascript.

Use label onmousemove event to trap the event, and set textbox visibility to true.
[You can easily write the code for yourself]